# caching_sha2_password и php 7.3

Tags: php, mysql

не работает аутентификация c `caching_sha2_password` на `php 7.3` для mysql8. В интернете пишут, что эта версия не имеет такой проблемы. Но она есть, и что делать - не понятно. Ставить на старый способ аутентификации, который все предлагают - не хочу. Помогите найти решение. Сам код ошибки:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализацию caching_sha2_password в 7.3, 7.2 и 7.1 откатили из-за проблем, детальнее смотрите обсуждение [вот к этому коммиту](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/d6e81f0bfd0cb90586dd83d4fd47a4302605261a). И коммит с [откатом изменений](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/03740ef7dffcc80530a89ebde3ccf5464f7f18e6).

Почему не упомянуто ни в документации ни даже в `changelog` - удивляет очевидно не только меня.